# SQL Server 2012 query to return x amount of rows from current position

Tags: sql-server

From rownumber 1 in the result, I need to return the 4 subsequent rows, and the 5 preceding rows.
How can I do this in SQL 2012?

```
select ROW_NUMBER() over(Order by Symbol ) as row,optionsID,WatchListID,Symbol,CallPut,Strike
  from STREAMER.dbo.options
 where WatchlistID = 1 and Strike > 119 and CallPut = 'C' 
 order by Strike
```

[enter link description here](http://screencast.com/t/yKIYflvP)

Comment: What defines a row as preceding a row with rownumber = 1?

Comment: my Options table has a couple of thousand rows. with the above statement I find records that have Strike > 119 and CallPut=C.  however I need to return a range of 9 records in total; 5 records prior to the first record from above result, and the next 4 records from the 1st record from above result, for a total of 9

Comment: and I have to add that all 9 records need to adhere to the WatchlistID = 1 and Strike > 119 and CallPut = 'C'  condition.

Comment: From the screenshot attached to the question, can you tell us which is the 1st subsequent and the 1st preceding record?

Comment: http://screencast.com/t/q7oUkUuc

Comment: So I need to return the highlighted 9 rows. But I have to start by looking for the 1st record where Strike > 120, and then go back 5 records, and forward 4 records. all having to meet the fore mentioned condition

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `UNION` in order to append the 5 preceding records to your result set:

```
select TOP 4 ROW_NUMBER() over(Order by Symbol ) as row,optionsID,WatchListID,Symbol,CallPut,Strike
from STREAMER.dbo.options
where WatchlistID = 1 and Strike > 119 and CallPut = 'C' 

union all

select TOP 5 -1 * (ROW_NUMBER() over(Order by Symbol desc )) as row,optionsID,WatchListID,Symbol,CallPut,Strike
from STREAMER.dbo.options
where WatchlistID = 1 and Strike <= 119 and CallPut = 'C' 
order by Strike
```

You can optionally multiply `ROW_NUMBER()` of the second set by -1, to get the negative order of the preceding records.

Comment: thank you very much, that works, just had to change order by to OptionsID. I was experimenting with the ROWS Preceding and Following procedures, but no luck.

Comment: @PtheGr8 You' re welcome. You can accept this post as an answer to your question, if it really helped you solve your ploblem,so that other people having a similar problem might benefit from this post.